# VBScript InputBox - How to identify when the Cancel button is pressed?

Tags: vbscript

How can I make my VBScript cancel a process when the cancel button is pressed? When pressing "OK" I'd like the VBScript to open a new `InputBox`. I've gotten this to kinda work, but I'd also like to give a function the "Cancel" button. A function that whould stop the whole VBScript from opening any other `MsgBox` or `InputBox`.

I have tried something like this:

```
Set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
strtext = InputBox("text")
    vbCancel
If vbCancel then 
  WScript.Quit
End if
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> When both helpfile and context are supplied, a Help button is
>   automatically added to the dialog box.
>
> If the user clicks OK or presses ENTER, the InputBox function returns
>   whatever is in the text box. **If the user clicks Cancel, the function
>   returns a zero-length string ("")**.

The bold part above is not exactly true. 
A user can cancel an InputBox dialog in many ways; by closing dialog, clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, or pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, and so on. In all cases except pressing <kbd>⏎</kbd> or clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> InputBox returns `Empty` (an uninitalized variant, its value is 0 for numeric, zero-length string ("") for string implicitly) and it means the dialog dismissed.
Since there's an implicit conversion between a zero-length string ("") and `Empty` variables, looking for zero-length string equality as MSDN suggested is not always an appropriate solution(*e.g.* in a logic where zero-length string means "use default", not cancelled).

```vb
Dim retval
    retval = InputBox("txt")
If IsEmpty(retval) Then
    'cancelled
    MsgBox "operation has been cancelled"
Else
    'something has entered even zero-length
    MsgBox retVal
End If
```

Comment: kinda works, but after the inputbox its suposed to open a new one.

Comment: @AvatarLandRazer not kinda, just works. how did you implemented? you may misunderstand the concept. simply, assign the inputbox's result to a variable, then check that the variabe is empty or not. that's it.

Comment: i acctually have gotten the whole script to work but 1 last thing now. ur solution was realy helpfull. thanks alot. but is there a way to restart the script by pressing ok aswell?

Comment: @AvatarLandRazer you're welcome. feel free to ask another question for the restart thing.

Comment: Dim x
    x = MsgBox("finished! Whould you like to restart?",1,"title")
    If vbOK Then
#this_is_where_i_want_a_restart_option
 If vbCancel then
 'cancelled
 MsgBox("Thanks")
End If

is it posible to make a goto type thing? so it goes back to the start.

Comment: I never managed to make the IsEmpty(InputBox(...)) return true in MS Word 2016; esc, Cancel, the cross, always returns false

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba This was a `vbscript` question, so this hacky solution works only for it. Microsoft Office VBA is a complete different environment. Unlike VBScript, it seems that the InputBox function in VBA works exactly as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function#remarks).

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba Today I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909528/893670). It worked on my computer w/ Office 2016.