# VBA not recognizing Null value

Tags: vba, ms-access, null

Working in MSAccess.  I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a button based on the value of a text box.
The form was created off of a query.  I've made sure the value in the tbl_Manufacturer.Website is Null.  But the code keeps validating as false and drops into the next set of code.  What did I miss?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If ([Forms]![frm_Asset]![tbl_Manufacturer.WebSite]) = Null Then
            
        btn_Hyperlink.Visible = False
    
    Else
        
        btn_Hyperlink.Caption = [Forms]![frm_Asset]![tbl_Manufacturer.WebSite]
        btn_Hyperlink.Visible = True
    
    End If

End Sub
```

-Jeff

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is ever equal to Null, since Null is a missing value. `Something = Null` is always going to return `Null`, which evaluates to false.

If you want to test if a field is null, use the `IsNull` function:

```
If IsNull([Forms]![frm_Asset]![tbl_Manufacturer.WebSite]) Then
```

Comment: ISNULL!  Thank you Erik, completely forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

Try using IsNull instead:

If (IsNull([Forms]![frm_Asset]![tbl_Manufactuer.Website]) Then
......

[Testing if a string is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067215/testing-if-a-string-is-null)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the `IsNull` option presented by other answers, you can simply compare to an empty string, since this is a text box:

`If ([Forms]![frm_Asset]![tbl_Manufacturer.WebSite]) Is Not "" Then`