# Variant/String instead of Variant/Empty

Tags: excel, vba

I create a variant of 10 rows and 2 columns from a Range in a Worksheet with this code :

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim leRange As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
leRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(10, 2)).Value
```

The first column is always filled but not the second one.
When I check the `leRange` in the Locals windows, when there is nothing in the cell the value is `Empty` of type `Variant/Empty`. I would like to change it to `""` of type `Variant/String.

I could loop the variant to check and replace but i would like to know if there is a smarter way to do it, thanks !

Edit : The function, which takes those datas as argument, needs a variant of strings and i can't change it so i need to do the replacement.

Comment: Why? Looping will be as efficient as any alternative (not that I can see a lot of point).

Comment: This range will probably grow quickly in the future so i wanted to be sure it'll be efficient

Comment: Seems like premature optimization. `Variant` is a fairly efficient data type. Why spend CPU cycles in changing empty variants to empty strings unless you know that it is an actual problem?

Comment: @JohnColeman because the function which takes those datas asks for a variant with only string in it and i can't change it

Comment: @TmSmth then that is a different issue than the efficiency concern you raised in a different comment.

Comment: @JohnColeman i wanted to say that as i have no choice to replace it, what is the best way to do it

Comment: I don't think there would be any more efficient method. You could use `Evaluate` to get an array with empty strings in it but I doubt it would be more efficient.

Comment: It makes no difference. Pass a `Variant/Empty` to a function that accepts a `String`, the function merrily gets `vbNullString` - expect problems when the subtype is `Error` though, so before you pass it to the function, verify whether the variant is `Variant/Error` with `IsError`, then explicitly convert it to a `String` with `CStr` if you want.

Comment: Wait, *the function* - **what function**? Can we see at least its signature? "needs a variant of strings" makes no sense at all.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon `Pass a Variant/Empty to a function that accepts a String, the function merrily gets vbNullString` - nitpicker's corner: it will receive a zero-length string, not `vbNullString`. The difference [may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909528/11683) or may not be important.

Comment: You could use the Excel's evaluate function: leRange = [if(A1:b10="","",A1:b10)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `leRange As String` and you'll get a `String` that's empty. Your code has no bearing on the return type of `Range.Value`, that's for Excel to decide.

The problem is that `leRange` isn't just any other `Variant/Empty` here: the range isn't spanning a single cell, so what the variant contains is actually a 2D array of variants, and that's how things work. You can't change the variant subtype of individual array elements you're getting from the host appliation's object model.

`Variant/Empty` is not equivalent to an empty string: if a cell is effectively blank, then `IsEmpty` returns true. If a cell contains/evaluates to an empty string, then `IsEmpty` returns false.

Note that only a `Variant` can hold an `Error` value. If a cell evaluates to e.g. `#REF!`, the variant subtype will be `Variant/Error`, and `IsError` will return true for it - trying to assign such a value to a `String` will result in a *type mismatch* error.

Excel is giving you a variant array: your code needs to deal with a variant array. `Empty` easily compares to `""` or `vbNullString` (comparison evaluates to True) - there is no problem to solve, your worry about the variant subtype is misplaced, there's nothing to worry about.

---

> *Edit : The function, which takes those datas as argument, needs a variant of strings and i can't change it so i need to do the replacement.*

I'm not sure what this means, but if it means you're passing the whole 2D `Variant` array to a function that accepts a `String()` array, then yes, you need to declare a new array and copy your variants into strings, otherwise you can expect a type mismatch - this is as inefficient as you would expect it to be given a few hundreds/thousands of cells, but if this is about the handful of cells involved in the OP, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer ! (sorry for the first delete, i saw your edited your post in the meanwhile)

Comment: Regarding the function it's a matlab function in their excel add-in and the function definition is something like `functionName(Optional variableName as Variant)`. I have an error when the variant is not full of string, they probably iterate on the variant and don't accept other thing than string i guess

Comment: @TmSmth possible. In that case you can declare a `String()` array, and populate it with your cell values - there's no shortcut for that, unfortunately. Next time, make sure your question includes *all* the relevant context ;-)

Comment: Sorry for that ! I've accepted your answer as you give some interesting details.